# jQuery UI and horizontal sortable - items shifting to the left when dragged

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/2675/

As soon I start dragging an element, the next ones shift a little bit to the left.

Floating the elements is a common solution to have an horizontal sortable, but I'm wondering if there is a way to stop items from shifting as you start dragging?

Css:

```
#draggable1 { background:#ff0000; width: 150px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em; }
#draggable2 { background:#00ff00; width: 150px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em; }
#draggable3 { background:#0000ff; width: 150px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em; }

#sortable { width: 700px; height: 35px;  }

#sortable > div { float: left; }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are using a padding for each draggable div (padding: 0.5em;).
You need to remove it and create a new container for it.

Process:

- Add p tag inside your draggables div.
- Remove the padding of your draggable div and it to the new tag (p
  here)

And your good to go =)

`Here is an example`: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/2676/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a placeholder and define its class in your css as the exact same size as your elements. The code is below and here is a working jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/sP3UZ/2706/

Also for good measure, here is a link to the placeholder documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-placeholder

### HTML

```
<div class="demo">
    <div id="sortable" class="ui-state-default">
        <div id = "draggable1" class="ui-state-default">Home</div>
        <div id = "draggable2" class="ui-state-default">Contact Us</div>
        <div id = "draggable3" class="ui-state-default">FAQs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#draggable1 { 
    background:#ff0000; 
    width: 150px; 
    height: 35px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
}
#draggable2 { 
    background:#00ff00; 
    width: 150px; 
    height: 35px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
}
#draggable3 { 
    background:#0000ff; 
    width: 150px; 
    height: 35px; 
    padding: 0.5em; 
}
#sortable { 
    width: 700px; 
    height: 35px;  
}
#sortable > div { 
    float: left; 
}
.sortable-placeholder {
    width: 150px; height: 35px; padding: 0.5em;
}
```

### JS

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder"
});
```

Good luck!

Best,

Josh