# How to add horizontal scroll in kanban board that made using jQuery-UI sortable

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I created a kanban board using Ruby on Rails and jQuery-ui sortable. In this kanban board user can drag and drop tickets into individual columns according to its status.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of columns and kanban board]

I want vertical scrollbar in individual columns and horizontal scrollbar for entire kanban board both the thing together. Here I am adding template code for this structure.

```html
<div class="kanban-view">
  <div class="kanban-view-m d-flex justify-content-between">
    <!-- Column 1 -->
    <div class="kanban-view-board">
      <div class="kanban-column-wrapper">
        <div class="kanban-head">
        </div>
        <div class="kanban-column">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Column 2 -->
    <div class="kanban-view-board">
      <div class="kanban-column-wrapper">
        <div class="kanban-head">
        </div>
        <div class="kanban-column">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Column 3 -->
      <div class="kanban-view-board">
        <div class="kanban-column-wrapper">
          <div class="kanban-head">
          </div>
          <div class="kanban-column">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In above code basically I want vertical scrollbar for `kanban-column` class and horizontal scrollbar for `kanban-view` main class. and I have total 11 columns with width of 323px; each. So need that horizontal scrollbar.

**Used Technologies :**
HTML, SCSS, Ruby on Rails, jQuery

I tried too many things but did not work. I also went through with some blogs and stackoverflow answers as well. Either horizonatal scrollbar is working or vertical scrollbar is working not both together and I want both the functionality together without any third party javascript library.

I started with this basic thing by applying overflow properties.

For Vertical - Columns

```css
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
```

For Horizontal - Container

```css
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

---

Links for the references which I followed :

[jQuery UI Sortable: Prevent horizontal scrolling with connected lists between full height columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55691251/jquery-ui-sortable-prevent-horizontal-scrolling-with-connected-lists-between-fu)

https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/need-help-to-get-horizontal-scroll-bar-into-kanban-board/

[jQuery UI and horizontal sortable - items shifting to the left when dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918917/jquery-ui-and-horizontal-sortable-items-shifting-to-the-left-when-dragged)

As per jquery-ui documentation they provided scroll by default but it's not working.
https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-scroll

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]